# FFMpeg and Handbrake video size differences

Tags: ffmpeg, video, conversion, video-conversion

I have to use ffmpeg on my windows OS because I need different filters and settings but I noticed that the videos I'm translating are a bit big and ffmpeg disappointed me when I started trying handbrake with the same settings. Although Handbrake and FFMpeg were on the same settings, Handbrake saved about 1GB and made a better quality conversion. I thought the problem was in the parameters and I did hours of testing but the result is the same.

Example Conversion Details:

[+] Original Video: **14.3 GB** (15,412,242,171 bytes)

**Handbrake Settings:**

```
"Encoder": "nvenc_h264",
"Level": "auto",
"Preset": "fast",
"profile": "high",
"Quality": 23

Output Size: 1.94 GB
```

**FFMpeg Settings:**

```
-c:v h264_nvenc -preset p3 -profile:v high -qmin 23 -qmax 52 or -crf 23

Output Size: 3.60 GB
```

I've tested not only constant quality but also other variations, No matter what I did, the result is always the same on average and the video quality is worse even though ffmpeg is about +1 GB more.

I can't understand why Handbrake converts video with better quality even though it has less video size, I know that it uses ffmpeg libraries as a logic, but I don't know what makes it special in handbrake. Do you think this is normal?

Comment: Handbrake uses the x264 encoder for video conversion. HB is in no way a front end for ffmpeg.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But when using nvenc_h264 encoding, shouldn't they both give similar results?

Comment: Check your preset throroughly.

Comment: @SweetNGX the hardware encoder has many presets and while the option set it restricted compared to a software encoder it still has a lot of options. One may be aware or more features available at your GPU than the other.